# How do i send the data to edit boxes on the same page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following page generated

[image]

when i click the Edit link, the record data must be sent to the input boxes on teh same page (without refreshing the page)

currently i have the controller code and views

**controller: ProductCategory**

```
    public class ProductCategoryController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /ProductCategory/

        TUDBEntities _db = new TUDBEntities();

        public ActionResult Index(string Code)
        {
            var categories = _db.mt_ProductCategories
                                .Where(pc => Code == "" || Code == null|| pc.CatCode == Code)
                                .Select(
                                c => new ProductCategory {
                                    Id = c.Id, 
                                    CategoryCode = c.CatCode, 
                                    Name = c.CatName, 
                                    Url = c.Url 
                                });

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_ProductCategoryList", categories);
            }

            return View(categories);

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(ProductCategory userData)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    mt_ProductCategories cat = new mt_ProductCategories { CatCode = userData.CategoryCode, CatName = userData.Name };
                    // TODO: Add insert logic here
                    _db.mt_ProductCategories.Add(cat);
                    _db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");                    
                }

                return View();
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var category = _db.mt_ProductCategories
                            .Where(pc => pc.Id == id)
                            .Select(pc => new ProductCategory 
                            { Id=pc.Id, CategoryCode=pc.CatCode,Name=pc.CatName }).ToList();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", category);
        }
}
```

**Index view**

```
@model IEnumerable<eComm1.Models.ProductCategory>

@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "ProductCategory", 
    new AjaxOptions { 
 HttpMethod="POST", 
 UpdateTargetId="prod-grid", 
 InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
 OnSuccess="loaddivdata"

}))
{

  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="Code">Category Code</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control focus" id="Code" name="CategoryCode" placeholder="Product category code" >
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="ProdName">Product Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ProdName" name="Name" placeholder="Product Name">
  </fieldset>
     <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
<hr />
<div id="prod-grid">
    @Html.Partial("_ProductCategoryList", @Model)
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('.focus :input').focus();
    });


    function loaddivdata() {        
        $('#prod-grid').html();
        $('#Code, #ProdName').val('');

    };




    //    $('#prod-grid').load(function () {
    //        $.ajax({
    //            url:'ProductCategoryController/Index', 
    //            method:'GET', 
    //            type:'application/html',
    //            success: function () { alert('called');}
    //        });

    //    });
    //});
</script>
```

**Partial View: _ProductCategoryList**

```
@model IEnumerable<eComm1.Models.ProductCategory>

<div class="panel panel-default">


@if (Model.Count() == 0) {   <div class="panel-heading">Product Categories - <span style='color:red;font-weight:bold' >0 RESULTS FOUND</span></div> 
}else{
      <!-- Default panel contents -->
  <div class="panel-heading">Product Categories</div>
}


  <!-- Table -->
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url)
        </td>
        <td>
            @*@Html.beActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })*@

            @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "ProductCategory", new { id=item.Id}, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "", OnSuccess = "loadformdata" }) | 
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "ProductCategory", new { id=item.Id}, new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod="POST", UpdateTargetId="", OnSuccess="loadformdata"}) 

         </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>


</div>
```

How do i modify my code to send data those input control and in my code how do i create hidden field for Id value so it can be send to the Edit(collection, int id) action to update the record?

for Stephen Muecke, i have added my jquery files through the bundles

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ecomm").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*", 
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"
        ));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
    // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
        "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
        "~/Content/bootstrap.css", 
        "~/Content/style.css"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
}
```

In the partial view

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "ProductCategory", new { id = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", OnSuccess = "loadformdata" }) | 
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "ProductCategory", new { id=item.Id}, new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod="POST", OnSuccess="loadformdata"})
```

in the index view the following js function:

function loadformdata() {

```
var cells = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
alert(cells.eq(0).text());
//$('#Code').val(cells.eq(0).text());
//$('#ProdName').val(cells.eq(1).text());
```

}

To: Stephen Muecke: 
i have removed above loadformdata() and put everything as you said. [this youtube video shows](https://youtu.be/yvdXGCBJPWQ) the problem that still does not call that click event

To: Steven Meucke: 
there's still no luck, for ease i have added a alert() in the function and the alert() won't show. [Here is the video](https://youtu.be/a4pIGNDeYXQ)

Comment: There are multiple ways. You can write JQuery on edit click that will set the values or can have ajax call to controller method and set the values on success.

Answer (score 1):

Give you 'Edit' link a class name (say) `class="edit"` and handle its `.click()` event to update the form controls

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
  var cells = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
  $('#Code').val(cells.eq(0).text());
  $('#ProdName').val(cells.eq(1).text());
  return false; // cancel the default redirect
});
```

Side note: You could just replace the `ActionLink()` code with `<a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>` and the `return false;` line is not necessary.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it did not work, where should i add this click function is in the partial page or index view? 

The other thing when i add the function or anyother function that has the $ (Jquery)function in it, IE throws an error "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined" why this js error occurs in IE?

Comment: In the main view (scripts should never be in partial views). `'$' is undefined` means you have not included `jquery-{version}.js` in the view. Also make sure your scripts are at the bottom of the page (immediately before the closing `</body>` tag, or inside`document.ready

Comment: i have added my jquery files through the bundles, i have updated the post with it just now!

Comment: You have multiple duplicate files which may be causing an issue. e.g. `~/bundles/ecomm` contains `jquery-{version}.js` and `jquery-2.1.4.min.js` then `~/bundles/jquery` includes it again for the 3rd time. You also have multiple copies of `bootstrap.js`, `jquery.unobtrusive*` and `jquery.validate*`

Comment: i was using the ajax actionlink method for now : ) when i put an alert() in the function loadformdata() and with code lines         var cells = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
        alert(cells.eq(0).text()); text showed as blank

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your last comment. What does the `loadformdata()` method have to do with my answer?

Comment: you have suggested to use just <a> but i want to stick with the original code with ActionLink, when do so, i have added an alert() to test what was received in the function loadformdata() and it showed empty for cells.eq(0).text()

Comment: What? The script I have used cancels the default event (you said you do not want to refresh the page) the `loadformdata()` should never even be called. I assuming your not understanding my answer at all. Its a separate script that handles the .click() event of the link, gets the values of the code and name in the corresponding row and updates the 2 textboxes. `loadformdata()` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: i have removed the 'return false' so now my function gets called, i have updated my post with the edited code

Comment: I cant even see a function called `loadformdata()` - what does it do? And why on earth do you have it when whatever code is in it should be inside the script I have shown. The only function I can see is `loaddivdata()` which clears the value of the textboxes.

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke check it now please :) sorry for the delay

Comment: What are you doing? I have given you an answer that works! Use it exactly as it is. Get rid of the `function loadformdata()` function - there is no `$(this)` inside that function.

Comment: please take a look at my youtube video that shows the problem with the page. i have updated the original post with a video link!

Comment: Now I see you dynamically loading the table!. Then you need to use event delegation - its `$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {` instead of `$('.edit').click(function() {` (but `document` should be replaced with the closest ancestor which exists on the page when you first generate the view which I assume is `'#prod-grid'`)

Comment: unfortunately still the same problem i have updated my post with comments and a new video

Comment: Then `'#prod-grid'` is not the correct ancestor - just start with `$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {`

Answer (score 0):

write script for ajax call:

```
$('#edit').click(function () {
         // var data = {here you will pass item.id }
        $.ajax({
            url:'ProductCategoryController/Edit', 
            data: {id : data}
            method:'GET',
            success: function (data) { 
                   //clear html page here
                   //reload html page by passing 'data' passes in function
             //e.g. suppose html page id is 'xyz' then $("#xyz").html(data)
                  }
        });

    });
```