# why delete failed to removed the record?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following action for the **delete** operation:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id, EmployeeDeleteViewModel collection)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Employee e = new Employee 
            { 
                EmpId = collection.EmpID, 
                FirstName = collection.FirstName, 
                LastName = collection.LastName, 
                DepartmentId = collection.DepartmentID 
            };

            db.Employees.Remove(e);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = id });
        }

        // TODO: Add update logic here

        return View(collection);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

the **delete view** is:

```
@model VirtualCampus2.Models.EmployeeDeleteViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>

<fieldset>
    <legend>EmployeeDeleteViewModel</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmpID)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmpID)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DepartmentName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DepartmentName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DepartmentID)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DepartmentID)
    </div>
</fieldset>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

When i click delete on the delete view the following error occurs:

1. to action method's second parameter "collection", it sends a collection with zeros and null in their properties
2. does not delete the record

Here is [video that shows the problem](https://youtu.be/c7dn0qdpqyE)

why this happens and how do i fix this?

To Steve: 
I have made the changes by creating a separate view model and a delete action:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class EmpDeleteCommitViewModel
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
}
```

the actions **Delete methods:**

```
        [HttpGet]//this works fine, gets the record to show on view
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var empList = db.Employees.ToList();

            var employee = empList.Where(e => e.EmpId == id).Select(e => new EmployeeDeleteViewModel 
            {
                EmpID=e.EmpId, 
                FirstName= e.FirstName, 
                LastName=e.LastName, 
                DepartmentID=e.DepartmentId,
                DepartmentName=e.Department.Name
            }).FirstOrDefault();

            return View(employee);
        }        



[HttpPost] //BUT THIS DOES NOT WORK!, evm EmpID does not contain id value
public ActionResult Delete(EmpDeleteCommitViewModel evm)
        {
            try
            {
                var employee = db.Employees.Where(e => e.EmpId == evm.EmpID).FirstOrDefault();
                db.Employees.Remove(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = evm.EmpID });

            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no form controls (`<input>`) between form tags so there is nothing to post back when you submit the form. All you doing is generating some text to display the property values.

There is no need to include the `EmployeeDeleteViewModel collection` parameter in you method. Your `int id` parameter will be bound with the `id` of the employee assuming your using the correct routing, so all you need to to get the original data model from the database based on the `id` and then delete it.

Comment: Model state checking is no need 'cus im not sending a model?

Comment: There is nothing to check - your not posting back a model (the only thing you currently posting is the value of the `id`). Just remove the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` because if your model contains any validation attributes it will always fail.

Comment: if i remember right i can have two actions with the same signature if one is httpGet and other a httpPost? the reason for two, i need to display the deleting record on a page before deletion

Comment: You have not shown your GET method, but if it has the same signature, then you can always create a `public class DeleteVM { public int ID { get; set; } }` view model, then the delete method is `public ActionResult Delete(DeleteVM model) { ... }` The value of `model.ID` will contain the ID of the employee.

Comment: Alternatively you can change the method to (say) `public ActionResult ConfirmDelete(int id)` and then specify the action method name in the `BeginForm()` helper

Comment: i have added the VM and the Action but still not receiving the id value, i have updated my post as well

Comment: Did you not read my last comment - its `public int ID { get; set; }` (not `EmpID`)

Comment: Incidentally - did you ever sort [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013462/how-do-i-send-the-data-to-edit-boxes-on-the-same-page) out?

Comment: to be frank, i have given up on it for the time, 'cus i got jammed up with some nut and bolts in mvc but will come back to that laters